# Calendar on macOS 10.8.5 won't select app(-s) to run (only scripts are selectable)

Tags: calendar, calendar.app

Weird problem. Running MacMini running macOS 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) and I cannot get my calendar to run an app. This is a new issue because  up until recently I had no problem selecting apps to run. It is not currently possible to update macOS 10.8.5 to a newer version of macOS on this machine because of its current running jobs.

So I try creating a new event, have the event open file, point to app (saved from AppleScript Editor. The app works perfectly on its own BTW).
But whatever I do or try, whenever I choose to browse for a file to (have calendar) open the ONLY files I am allowed to select are .scpt-files. It's not only `.app`'s that aren't selectable. `.mov`, `.vob`, `.ifo` are also un-selectable.

Comment: No Mac is limited to 10.8.5. If it can run 10.8 it can run 10.11. I can't help you on 10.8, it's simply too old to remember its foibles. Maybe either upgrade to El Capitan, os ask this question on [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: What I meant was; not possible to update because of its current running jobs. The machine, likely, will update just fine. It's all the stuff on the machine I need to have running as is.

Comment: OK, no probs. Glad you figured it out:) My oldest VM is 10.10 these days, so I couldn't even try to check.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I am not the only one who have experienced this - but perhaps everyone else either gave up or solved the matter without consulting various web resources. I got this solution orally from a colleague who is macOS skilled.

#### This is a macOS 10.8.5 (perhaps not exclusively?) bug.

To get around it; quit iCal, restart Mac, make **one** calendar entry with [open-file] - and repeat process. Apparently iCal can only manage one file-opening at a time and needs to... I dunno, recalculate eveything before  accepting new deals.

So there you have it! In the hope someone else may profit from this "solution"/work-around.